# Is it possible to sent XMLHttpRequest post request from the google chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I put my code to the git repository, that you can replay it
https://github.com/o1eksiy/chrome-post-extension
Every time when I send post-request the google chrome cancel it. Could you, please, explain what I do wrong?

Comment: Your `manifest.json` files has multiple `//` sequences in it, which aren't valid JSON. Did Chrome really let you install this extension with syntax errors in the manifest?

Comment: As a separate issue, your button will cause the form to immediately submit, since you don't `preventDefault` in your click handler. It will probably still send the Ajax request just before the page navigates away, but you will not have time to do anything with the response, if you were hoping to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forget that I used <form> tag. Sorry for my  
distraction. About your question, yes manifest.json supports //